# liquid layout.. make buttons float right

Tags: java, swing

With this code the buttons align left, but the glue doesn't expand.. I wanted buttons 2 and 3 to float right.

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panelBottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("1");
panelBottom.add(btnNewButton);

Component glue = Box.createGlue();
panelBottom.add(glue);

JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("2");
panelBottom.add(btnNewButton_1);

JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("3");
panelBottom.add(btnNewButton_2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use `glue`, you need to use a BoxLayout.

Comment: Or instantiate [`Box`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html).